# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1146 (42S02): Table 'd1.tblname' doesn't exist

Tags: python, mysql, database, mariadb

Right now i am doing a project in which I have to create SQL database using **mysql.connector** for python on RPi. 
The purpose of this project is to create SQL Database from the text files present in a directory of raspberry pi. My motive is to create tables in database as of the names of text files and then inserting data from text files to their corrosponding tables.

I have written a python script which sccessfuly connects to my database and creates my required table but I have problems which I try to load my data into created tables.

My code looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
hostname = 'localHost'
username = 'userName'
password = 'password'
database = 'databseName'
portname = 'portNumber'

from mysql.connector.constants import ClientFlag
import os,csv,string,sys
import mysql.connector
print('\nConnecting SQL database using host = '+hostname+' ,username = '+username+' ,database = '+database+' ,port = '+portname+'.')
print('\n')


myConnection = mysql.connector.connect(user=username, passwd=password,host=hostname,port=portname,db=database,client_flags=[ClientFlag.LOCAL_FILES])
myCursor =myConnection.cursor()

rootDir = '/mnt/Wdrive/pc70/SK/E07'

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
        for fname in fileList:
                tblname = os.path.basename(fname).split('.')[0]
                #print('%s' %(tblname))
                print(tblname)
                sql= 'CREATE TABLE %s (Datum varchar(12), Uhrzeit varchar(13), UpsACT_V varchar(6), UpsPRE_V varchar(6), IpsACT_A varchar(6), IpsPRE_A varchar(6), PpsACT_W varchar(6), PpsPRE_W varchar(10)) % tblname
                myCursor.execute(sql)
                myConnection.commit()
                finalpath= os.path.join(rootDir,fname)
                print(finalpath)
                loadData= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'finalpath' INTO TABLE tblname COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' "
                #loadData= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE join INTO TABLE tblname COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' IGNORE 11 lines"
                myCursor.execute(loadData)
                myConnection.commit()
```

When I run the above program I get the following error

```
   Connecting SQL database using host = **** ,username = **** ,database = **** ,port = ****.


CM_lad_19Dez2018_14Uhr38
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "25createtable.py", line 39, in <module>
    myCursor.execute(loadData)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 491, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 683, in cmd_query
    statement))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 601, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1146 (42S02): Table 'd1.tblname' doesn't exist
```

My program is creating tables as per my requirement but it's not loading data into it and exits the code with the above mentioned error.

I need to tweak `loadData= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'finalpath' INTO TABLE **tblname** COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' "` in a way that it reads the corrosponding table in my database
As far as I know the error lies with **tblname** variable. Any ideas?

Comment: I think there's a missing quote mark in the latter part of your code

Comment: can you specify where?

Comment: if you think it should be like this `loadData= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE finalpath INTO TABLE 'tblname' IGNORE 11 lines"`. it gives me the error
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'finalpath INTO TABLE 'tblname'  IGNORE 11 lines' at line 1`

Comment: `tblname` appears to be the name of a variable, a string object to be precise, taken from a filename. You substitute it into your SQL string for the CREATE TABLE statement. For the LOAD DATA statement you use the variable name `tblname` itself as literal identifier in the SQL; you do not substitute its value as you do in the CREATE TABLE statement. It feels like this should rather read `"LOAD DATA [...] INTO TABLE %s [...]" % tblname`

Comment: Okay Thanks. I will try this in the morning and will comment whatever the result comes out.

Comment: So I have tried your recommended change
`loadData= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE [..] INTO TABLE %s [..]" % tblname`
 and it's giving me the following error,
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[..] INTO TABLE CM_lad_19Dez2018_14Uhr38 [..]' at line 1`
here I understand how it is reading the table name but i am not sure if it is reading the txt file from which it should load the data,I am confused that what should I pass in place of [...]

Comment: @shmee looking forward to the clarification.

Comment: I did not want to type the whole SQL string in the comment. The [...] are just placeholders. Use your whole string, just replace the `tblname` as shown in my comment

Comment: @shmee thansk for your valuable responses, I am not asking you to write me a full SQL query, I had confusion in `[...]` that's why I asked for clarification.I am totally new to this stuff....
What I am not understanding is that what you say use your whole string, you are talking about the name of the text file ?? I am totally messed up.

Comment: Assuming that you want to load the content of the file you named the table after into said table, your whole SQL statement should look like this: `"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{}' INTO TABLE {} COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' ".format(fname, tblname)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I have solved this problem with another  statement. I will post that in the morning so that others can take help from that.

Comment: `loadData= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '%s' " %finalpath + "INTO TABLE %s" %tblname` Assuming that the tables are already created using Create Table query, This load command is loading data of files in it's corrosponding table.